# Java garbage collector - how can I be sure that it has been executed

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have to parse a 3 giga xml file and generate an altered one with SAX.

To do it I'm using serialized objects, one thread.

First tests are great with small files. But with a 3 giga file it will generate a lot of unused instances.

I want to be sure that garbage collector has been executed.

My ideas :

```
if(...)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
  {
            System.gc();
  }
}
```

or another idea :

```
if(...)
  {
    Thread.sleep(1 800 000);//30mn
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                System.gc();
            }
    Thread.sleep(1 800 000);//30mn
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                System.gc();
            }
  }
```

I don't know many things about java garbage collector... What do you think about it ?

Comment: GC will be executed whenever the JVM considers that necessary, you can not do anything about it, even invoking that by yourself using **system.gc** is not guaranteed to be done at the moment you invoke it...

Comment: `System.gc()` gives the JVM a hint to do garbage collection. There is no guarantee that it will happen. Generally in Java you cannot force allocated memory to be freed.

Comment: "it will generate a lot of unused instances" - maybe jvm will invoke gc because of this very reason !

Comment: Have you tried? This kind of question without a profiled run un-answerable

Comment: thanks for the advice !

Comment: well I don't have a 3 giga file for the moment to do my test. with a 150mo it takes me 2 seconds to generate 6800 serialized instances. I have a ssd hard drive

Comment: Initially, do nothing and hope for the best. It's quite probable that it just works. Otherwise, you might want to add some GC calls (one or maybe two, not 50) and maybe even some sleep (but surely not minutes) at a proper place, i.e., after some processing has been done and the memory is no more needed. Your above ideas are extreme... I'm sure this won't help. The whole processing should take a few minutes at most.

Comment: ok for do nothing and hope for the best. My code here : https://github.com/BenjaminBettan/XML_SAX

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be sure that garbage collector has been executed.

`System.gc();` may have some delays before that the GC acts.

Generally, you should not need to invoke `System.gc();`, overall if you have some pauses between processings as in your sample code.
If you don't do pause between big processings, invoking `System.gc();` may make sense but still you should do some benchmark to check whether if is really required and that it doesn't create on the contrary slow downs.

Besides, invoking `System.gc();` will be helpless if the objects that you want to free are not eligible to be.

> But with a 3 giga file it will generate a lot of unused instances.

You don't show code but unused instances don't mean necessarily instances not referenced any longer by living objects.

The GC collects and sweeps only objects that are eligible to be : that is objects that are not referenced any longer by any living object.
To do it, you have to focus on reducing the scope of the objects that you manipulate to make it as short as required.